# Can I get column names from a string?

Tags: r, data.table, evaluation

I would like to combine columns of a data.table data table according to some string and then remove them from the table.

For instance I have a data table `dt` with columns `price_t` and `price_t1`. I would like to create a new variable that is defined as:

```r
s <- 'log(price_t + price_t1 + 5)'
```

I would like there to be a new column that is defined by the formula in `s` and the columns `price_t` and `price_t1` to be gone.

The variables to be deleted are stored only in the string, so I have to parse out from `s` what needs to be deleted. The string would contain functions that are present in the environment, so either standard functions like `log` or user defined functions, column names in the data. table, and constants.

Some more examples

```r
s1 <- 'price_t + 5'

RegCoef <- function(x, y) {
 m <- lm(y ~ x)
 return(coef(m)[2])
}

s2 <- 'RegCoef(price_t, price_t1)'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `eval(parse`

```
library(data.table)
library(stringr)
nm1 <-  str_extract_all(s, str_c("\\b(", str_c(names(dt), 
                   collapse="|"), ")\\b"))[[1]]
nm1
#[1] "price_t"  "price_t1"

dt[, s := eval(parse(text = s))][, (nm1) := NULL][]
```

#### data

```
dt<-data.table(price_t=c(1,2,3),price_t1=c(3,2,1))
```

Comment: Close but I still need to define the variables to be deleted myself. I would like to automatically extract them from the string.

Comment: @badmax that is possible, but can you explain what kind of strings would in generral be used

Comment: I added a description in the post.

Comment: I get 'price_t' twice as the value for nm1.

Answer (score 0):

```
dt<-data.table(price_t=c(1,2,3),price_t1=c(3,2,1))

dt$s<-log(dt$price_t+dt$price_t1 + 5)
```

like this?

Comment: No, the formula is in a string.